# What is the meaning of "before getting behind the wheel"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> UVA rays are constantly present, no matter the season or the weather. If you think you can't get sun damage on a cloudy day, tell that to the UVA rays. They are so powerful that they also penetrate some clothing and even glass. (When was the last time you applied sunscreen **before getting behind the wheel?**)
> <sub>Source: [about.com article, *UVA and UVB Rays*](http://skincare.about.com/od/sunkissedglow/a/UVAandUVBRays.htm)</sub>

Does it mean *When was the last time you applied sunscreen before getting into the sun?*

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet#Glass_filtering

Comment: I take it that your question about how to 'paint' a sentence refers to the 'blockquote' formatting I have applied to your quotation. This is achieved by putting the character `>` before each line. You may find many more formatting possibilities by clicking on the `?` button at the top right of the box in which you enter your question.

Comment: Also, instead of "paint", "highlight" would be a better word in English for this.

Answer (score 3):

As Lascivious Grace states, *[getting behind the wheel](http://www.yourdictionary.com/behind-the-wheel)* is driving a vehicle. That's because it's actually *getting behind the (steering) wheel.*

Note the previous sentence of your paragraph.

> They are so powerful that they also penetrate some clothing and even glass.

The author wants to convey that no matter what, these rays are everywhere. If you think that you are merely driving a car and thus safe, it's not so. The rays *penetrate* the glass and affect your skin. The author is asking and indirectly advising that applying sun screen is better even though your plan is just to drive.

Answer (score 2):

**Behind the wheel** is an idiom that implies *driving a car*.

> ***behind the wheel*** (*also at the wheel*)
>
> **driving a vehicle**
>
> *Mia was behind the wheel, and Kim was studying the map.*
> <sub>Source: [thefreedictionary.com](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/behind+the+wheel)</sub>

Thus, in your paragraph:

> the last time you applied sunscreen before getting behind the
>   wheel

simply means *the last time you applied sunscreen before you went on a drive.*

Answer (score 1):

"Behind the wheel" means "driving a car." The wheel in that saying refers to the steering wheel, which the drivers sits behind. The label is saying that you can still get sunburn even when inside of a car.